# Easing function with Velocity.js don't work properly

Tags: javascript, velocity.js, jquery-easing

I call a velocity.js function to show/hide a navbar up to the viewport.
I have two functions to achieve this.

```
function openNav(){
$('.navigation').velocity({height: "87vh"},{duration: 1000, display: 'block'}); }


function closeNav(){
$('.navigation').velocity({height: '0vh'}, {duration: 1000, display: 'none'}); }
```

Now I want to add different easing function in both animations.

So, From [Velocity.js Easing Doc](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#easing) :

```
function openNav(){
$('.navigation').velocity({height: "87vh"},{duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutBounce' , display: 'block'}); }


function closeNav(){
$('.navigation').velocity({height: '0vh'}, {duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutElastic' , display: 'none'}); }
```

But easing functions aren't properly applied and I see the default behavior

I've also tried to add easing in this way:

```
$element.velocity({height: '0vh'}, "easeOutElastic");
```

I'd like to know where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Back, bounce, and elastic easing types are not available in standard velocity.js.
From the documentation:

> Pre-packaged into Velocity are jQuery UI's easings, ***except for the back, bounce, and elastic easing types***.

But take a look at [Ease+ for Velocity.js](https://github.com/yuichiroharai/easeplus-velocity), it adds Back, Elastic, Bounce to velocity.js.

Comment: I'm getting Velocity v2 ready for public beta next week, so will see if I can add these easings into it before then. Thanks for pointing at that repo! :-)

Comment: They're now all supported in 2.0.2 (the next beta release) - everything except "Back" was added by 2.0.0

Answer (score -1):

TRY this

function openNav() { $('.navigation').velocity({ height: "87vh"},{duration: 1000, display: 'block'},{easing: 'easeOutBounce' }); }

Comment: That's never been how Velocity arguments work for easing, the original examples had the correct commands.